# Ruby finding duplicates in MongoDB

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I am struggling to get this working efficiently I think map reduce is the answer but can't getting anything working, I know it is probably a simple answer hopefully someone can help

**Entry Model** looks like this:

```
  field :var_name, type: String
  field :var_data, type: String
  field :var_date, type: DateTime
  field :external_id, type: Integer
```

If the external data source malfunctions we get duplicate data. One way to stop this was when consuming the results we check if a record with the same external_id already exists, as one we have already consumed. However this is slowing down the process a lot.  The plan now is to check for duplicates once a day. So we are looking get a list of Entries with the same external_id. Which we can then sort and delete those no longer needed.

I have tried adapting the snippet from here  https://coderwall.com/p/96dp8g/find-duplicate-documents-in-mongoid-with-map-reduce as shown below but get

**failed with error 0: "exception: assertion src/mongo/db/commands/mr.cpp:480"**

```
def find_duplicates

  map = %Q{
    function() {
      emit(this.external_id, 1);
    }
  }

  reduce = %Q{
    function(key, values) {
      return Array.sum(values);
    }
  }

  Entry.all.map_reduce(map, reduce).out(inline: true).each do |entry|
    puts entry["_id"] if entry["value"] != 1
  end

end
```

Am I way off? Could anyone suggest a solution? I am using Mongiod, Rails 4.1.6 and Ruby 2.1

Comment: Use a [unique index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/) and the [Mongoid syntax](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/indexing.html)

Comment: That seems a great solution. I will have a look at that with the drop dups set to true. Thank you.

Comment: FYI the `dropDups` option only applies on initial build of a unique index. Definitely use with caution as you may drop the "wrong" duplicate if one of the duplicates was more recently updated. In addition to adding a unique index on your `external_id` field, you may also want to consider using an [`upsert`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) (Mongoid exposes this as a standard [`upsert` method](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html#standard) on your Model class). Upsert means "update if found, otherwise insert  new doc".

Comment: If you are concerned about overhead of a unique index (and are OK to have duplicate documents exist until you clean them up) you could also consider using the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) to find duplicates. This would be more performant than your original notion of using Map/Reduce, and you could potentially limit documents based on a timestamp or ObjectID from the last dupe check. However, if you are updating these documents or the possibility of duplicates is high, the unique index approach would certainly be less convoluted.

Comment: @Stennie I will have a look at the Aggregation framework method.  I did tests with the unique index and found it only working on the initial build which is not going to work this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working using the suggestion in the comments of the question by Stennie using the Aggregation framework. It looks like this:

```
results = Entry.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group" => { 
    _id: { "external_id" => "$external_id"}, 
    recordIds: {"$addToSet" => "$_id" },
    count: { "$sum" => 1 } 
  }}, 
  { "$match" => { 
    count: { "$gt" => 1 } 
  }}
])
```

I then loop through the results and delete any unnecessary entries.